# How to convert a world generated Texture Coordinate into Object Texture Coordinate

Tags: uv, shaders, texture-coordinates

In the material shader editor, one can use a Texture Coordinate from  the Input, like generated, UV, object, etc.

For example the object texture coordinate,the main benefit is that it will allow you to apply a texture around a object without having to uvwrap it, however that object texture coordinate is linked to world coordinates, and when for example, a character has a material that uses the Object Texture Coordinate, when it bends it's geometry to follow a bone, it shifts the generated UV, because it's linked to world coordinates, and the result is similar to water dripping from a object.

*-Of course when using these methods to texture your models, you will need to use seamless textures, and if you want, you can enable box projection on the Image Texture to enhance seamless transitions.*

***My question:*** How we can convert this world generated UV data, into a object data?

So the texture will be binded to the mesh data like a UVWrapped model, maybe bake or export the UV data from the Object Texture to a static UV map. I tried already various methods, including using a Vector Transform node.

This may be benefical for quick projects in which we can texture a scenario/object very easily, or in which, detailing is not needed. We create a library of materials and just apply them to a object, brick patterns, concrete, etc.

[image: A simple Test.]